# Create a directory tree component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am working on a music player using electron and decided to give react a try, but I am stuck on creating a directory tree.

I'm using readdirp to get all directories recursively, but I have no idea how to build the tree; readdirp creates an array of objects with the following properties:

```
// dir.fullPath      :  'D:/Music/Artist/Album/name',
// dir.fullParentDir :  'D:/Music/Artist/Album',
// dir.path          :  'Artist/Album/name',
// dir.parentDir     :  'Artist/Album',
// dir.name          :  'name',
```

Tree structure:

```
D:/Music/Artist1
D:/Music/Artist1/Album1
D:/Music/Artist1/Album1/cd1
D:/Music/Artist1/Album1/cd2
D:/Music/Artist1/Album2
D:/Music/Artist2
D:/Music/Artist2/Album1
D:/Music/Artist2/Album2
```

With vanilla JS I loop over the array:

On the 1st iteration I create an element with **id=D:/Music/Artist1** (dir.fullPath), I search for an element with **id=D:/Music/** (dir.fullParentDir ), it doesn't exist so I add the element to a default element.

2nd iteration I create an element with **id=D:/Music/Artist1/Album1**, I search for an element with **id=D:/Music/Artist1**, it exists so I add it the the found element.

This gives me the correct nesting.

```
<div id="default">
    <div id="D:/Music/Artist1">
        <div id="D:/Music/Artist1/Album1">
              <div id="D:/Music/Artist1/Album1/cd1"></div>
              <div id="D:/Music/Artist1/Album1/cd2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="D:/Music/Artist1/Album2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="D:/Music/Artist2">
        <div id="D:/Music/Artist2/Album1"></div>
        <div id="D:/Music/Artist2/Album2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the same in react?

**Edit**

Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IncQP.jpg) is the array of objects returned by readdirp, object 1 is the parent dir of object 17 and object 18.

The nesting can be bigger than 1 level (updated the examples above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is a potential solution to what you are looking for...

I think it wise to use the `directory-tree` package as opposed to the `readdirp` package.

Pass the `TreeView` component a root prop like so `<TreeView root='c:\' />`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dirTree from 'directory-tree'; // use this istead of 'readdirp`


export default class TreeView extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            tree: null //initialize tree
        }

        this.renderTreeNodes = this.renderTreeNodes.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const { root } = this.props;
        const tree = dirTree(root);

        this.setState({ tree });
    }

    renderTreeNodes(children) {
        if (children.length === 0) return null;

        return (
            children.map(child => {
                return (
                    <div key={child.path} id={child.path}>
                        { child.hasOwnProperty('children') && child.type === 'directory'?
                            this.renderTreeNodes(child.children) : null}
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { tree } = this.state;

        return (
            <div id="default">
                <div id={tree.path}>
                    { this.renderTreeNodes(tree.children) }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Also there are two this.props.directories, I suppose it should be state instead of props. Added more info to the question. If I create react elements in a loop is it possible to search for them in the next iteration of the same loop? Like I do with vanilla js.

Comment: `return <div key={dir.fullPath} id={dir.fullPath}></div>` `Cannot read property 'fullPath' of undefined` dir is a string and not an array. And if I change to only dir, while I get no errors only the default div is displayed. https://pastebin.com/fsAzrrfB

Comment: gotcha, i just saw your edit about the possibility of multiple levels.  I will work on this some more and get back to you.

Comment: Are the results of the readdirp call ordered??? is the root the always the first element?

Comment: I think they are.

Comment: I took a different approach and changed the code block in the answer i posted.  It is more relevant to what you are actually looking for per your post edit earlier.  I havent tested it but I an help you debug it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150852/discussion-between-fbg13-and-canaan-seaton).